# Best model for geographical distribution of a characteristic prevalence?

Tags: regression, spatial, geography

I've data about the presence of a specific allele `E4` among different geographical region populations (e.g. `nord`,`center`,`south`).

Every sample has 2 allelic locus in which `E4` can be present/absent (and if present can be `1/2` or `2/2`).

I need to know if the allele `E4` is more represented in some particular region respect than the other.

I'm not very expert in this kind of "geographic" analysis, so I'd like to know what would be the "standard/best" statistical model to analyze such data.

I thought about Poisson regression, ANOVA etc but I'm not quite sure that they would take into consideration the prevalence in population and not only the presence of the allele.

This is an example of my data:

```
case_ID Sex Age DX_group    Allelic_conf    Region  Province    City
AX013   F   81  AD  E2/E3   Lazio   Roma    Roma
AX014   F   59  IAD E3/E3   Friuli-Venezia Giulia   Udine   Tolmezzo
AX015   F   76  control E3/E4   Toscana Grosseto    Arcidosso
AX016   M   63  AD  E4/E4   Sardegna    Oristano    Terralba
```

Comment: This does look like a job for a Poisson model. Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: edited with a data head

Comment: So are you only interested in E4 (and not E3)? And if so, is 1/2 or 2/2 an important distinction? And you are interested only in distribution per region? What is the population here, prevalence?

Comment: Basically I’m interested in E4 (if there could be a way to take into account E3, E2 as well it would be great, but secondary). 1/2 and 2/2 is important as division, as 2/2 double the risk related to the E4 allele presence. I’m interested in finding possible patterns of non-uniform distribution in the different regions, the population is a cohort of case and controls in Italy, overall prevalence is roughly 10% in cases and a tenth in controls. Thanks in advance @user2974951

Comment: Then this looks like it could be solved with Poisson regression. You would add variables for E - which type (2, 3, 4), another variable for 1/2 and 2/2, and a variable for region.